# Setting bits using Union in C

Tags: c, struct, field, bit

I am trying to modify certain bits in the bit fields using union as below.

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t bit1 : 1;
    uint8_t bit2 : 1;
    uint8_t bit3 : 1;
    uint8_t bit4 : 1;
    uint8_t reserved : 4;
} bit_fields_t;

typedef union all {
    uint8_t         status[sizeof(bit_fields_t)];
    bit_fields_t    bit;
} all_t;
```

I just wanna understand how I can modify, let's say, bit 4 using `status` variable in the union. Or what is the correct way to modify the bits in my struct.

Comment: You don't have have a variable whose value to modify

Comment: Note that the specific layout of bits in bit-fields is [implementation-defined and highly non-portable](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p11):

Comment: (cont) "An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit- field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. **The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined**. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified."

Answer (score 3):

> I just wanna understand how I can modify, let's say, bit 4 using
> status variable in the union

it is not a variable, only a union member. You need to declare the object of this union type and then modify it.

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t bit1 :1; 
    uint8_t bit2 :1;
    uint8_t bit3 :1;
    uint8_t bit4 :1;
    uint8_t : 4;
}bit_fields_t;

typedef union all {
    uint8_t          status;
    bit_fields_t    bit;
}all_t;

int main (void)
{
    all_t x = {.status = 0};
    x.bit.bit4 = 1;

    printf("0x%"PRIx8"\n", x.status);

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/P7cYveWd7